# Flutter Firebase Authentication requires 2 clicks for sign in

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, authentication

I just connected my app with firebase authentication but when i'm trying to click login button : it says

```
W/System  ( 6835): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

And here is my code about firebase authentication :
`

```
void signIn() async{
    final User? user = (await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: mailController.text, password: passController.text)).user;
    final uid = user!.uid;

    if(uid != null){
      if(this.mounted){
      setState((){
        success = 2;
        userMail = user.email!;
        userName = userMail;
        userName = userMail.replaceFirst(userName[0],"");
        userName = userName.substring(0,userName.indexOf("@"));
        userName = userName.replaceFirst(userName[0],userName[0].toUpperCase());
      });
    }}
    else{
      setState((){
        success = 3;
      });
    }
  }
```

`

```
if(success == 2){
                              if(userMail.startsWith("1")){
                                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => OgrenciPage(mail:userName)));
                              }
```

``

I've tried to creating sha-1 key, closing bluetooth connection but it never works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face this problem earlier then solve this by making the function Future asyn{} and by using try catch block.

In my case i created the login class model where I perform all All login/signup functionalities

Here is the example code where you can see how to manage this:

```
class Login {
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  Future<void> signInUser(
      String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(
            e.toString(),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share this algorithm for my code? probably i couldn't do this truly because it didn't work.

Comment: actually i solve this problem like this : i have an async functionality to onPressed function and code signIn() like this : await signIn() and it worked, but thx for everything.

Comment: Happy for you but it's a good practice to use try-catch block while dealing with async or api that require output from internet servers, that's why we use await inside try block instead of making whole method await. Make sure you have hands on it. :-)